# How to acess tuple/cell properties of MDX output through C#?

Tags: c#, mdx, adomd.net

I have an MDX query I am pulling through using Adomd.net where cmd contains the command text.

This, when run directly against a cube returns the following output, just a caption and the count integar, this being a measure:

```
TrueCount
   n
```

However, how do I access this measure/tuple/number through c# ?

I know how I can get the caption, TrueCount out (see below), but I don't know how to get the blooming number out.

```
//Execute the query, returning a cellset
CellSet cs = cmd.ExecuteCellSet();

//Output the column captions from the first axis
TupleCollection tuplesOnColumns = cs.Axes[0].Set.Tuples;

foreach (var column in tuplesOnColumns)
    if (!column.Members[0].Caption.Contains("All"))
        truecount.Add(new TrueCount() { CountTitle = column.Members[0].Caption });
```

Any ideas or pointers greatly appreciated - apologies for the thick question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used these functions to run MDX, but my experience with ADOMD is that the captions of rows and columns are accessed from a different object to the numbers in the middle. So I think you need to look at your `cs` object, and not within `cs.Axes`.

In ADOMD you just say `myNumber = cs(x, y).FormattedValue`

Hopefully that might lead you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Cells property of the CellSet, Axes only gets the labels. Something like:

```
Count = cs.Cells[column.TupleOrdinal,0].Value
```

Use `.FormattedValue` if you want the value with the cubes formatting rules for display.

I found it easier to use `cs.Axes[0].Positions` rather than the tuples member.